# Apache Camel exception handling

Tags: java, exception, apache-camel

I'm new to Camel and have some questions on Exception handling. I need to have 3 retry attempts for message processing, after exceeding attempts limit it's required to send the messages to deadLetterChannel. How can I combine maximumRedeliveries and errorHandler?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from ("direct:messageprocessing") //OR YOUR URI
.errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("log:DLC")
.maximumRedeliveries(3).redeliveryDelay(250).backOffMultiplier(2)).... <YOUR ROUTE CODE>
```